# X button control How to map keys to buttons

Tags: mouse, keymap

I want to map R and Shift to button 4 and 5 on my computer,how can I do this with X mouse Button Control?

Comment: Have a look at `xdotool` and `xbindkeys`.

Answer (score 1):

[image: XMBC]

You want to use the **Simulated Keys** event in X-Mouse Button Control. Make sure your {SHIFT} has the curly braces. The R just goes by itself.